# Regarding sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below sql query to insert the records from a table. The problem is when there is no records for select query i still want an record with the sequence number,null,'3' value inserted.  Nothing get's inserted when there is no record found for select query. how can i do it?

```
insert into test_details(seqnbr,trepid,type)
select '&seqid'
      ,REP_ID
      ,'3'
  FROM ref_details
 WHERE REP_ID >13;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Oracle 9i+:

To fill in gaps, you need to [create a list of sequencial values](http://oraqa.com/2006/01/20/how-to-generate-sequence-numbers-between-two-numbers/):

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DETAILS
  (seqnbr, trpid, type)
 SELECT '&seqid', rd.rep_id, '3'
     FROM (SELECT LEVEL + 13
             FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13) x
LEFT JOIN REF_DETAILS rd ON rd.rep_id = x.level
                        AND rd.rep_id > 13
```

...then LEFT JOIN to the table that can have gaps.

Comment: could you tell me more about the level what is level.

Comment: @Arav: `LEVEL` is an incrementing value for reference in Oracle's `CONNECT BY` syntax for recursive queries.  The value will start at 1, so the query adds 13 to start at the minimum value you specified in your question.  The link provides examples of how to set the upper limit to be based on a table value...

Answer (score 4):

One way would be

```
insert into test_details(seqnbr,trpid,type)
select '&seqid',rep_id,'3' from ref_details where rep_id>13
union all select '&seqid',null,'3'
from dual where not exists(
select 1 from ref_details where rep_id>13)
```

Comment: That will not account for gaps